# How to Pass Data Variable into Twilio Text Body

Tags: node.js, twilio

Using NodeJS server side, I have a variable with data in it called **lowestPrice**. I want to be able to pass this variable's data into the body of a Twilio text being sent.

Below is what I'm trying but it does not work.
Is this possible? If so, how do I accomplish this?

```
const accountSid = 'abc123';
const authToken = 'def456';
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.messages
  .create({
     body: 'Current Lowest Price: ' + $lowestPrice ,
     from: '+11234567890',
     to: '+10987654321'
    })
  .then(message => console.log(message.sid));
```

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with javascript you can do like this

```
const accountSid = 'abc123';
const authToken = 'def456';
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

let lowestPrice  = 100;

client.messages
  .create({
     body: `Current Lowest Price: ${lowestPrice}` ,
     from: '+11234567890',
     to: '+10987654321'
    })
  .then(message => console.log(message.sid));
```

**EDIT** - Using node.js

```
const { toPhoneNum, lowestPrice} = req.body;

client.messages
  .create({
     body: lowestPrice,
     from: '+11234567890',
     to: toPhoneNum
    })
  .then(message => console.log(message.sid));
```

Now you can pass the `Current Lowest Price: 100` message in the body

Comment: Fantastic @sumanth this worked, thank you. And apologies, I did not state that this was being used server side in NodeJS, I have updated my question.
May I ask a couple follow up questions? I see that in order for the lowestPrice variable to be read in the body as a variable and not as a string literal, you had to use ` backticks, this was intentional correct?
Where in any documentation is this mentioned?

Comment: Sumanth was using a  JS feature called [Template Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which is pretty common in JS nowadays. It's not explicitly mentioned in the Twilio docs as this is a language feature. For completion, it's worth mentioning that a string operation like `"Current Lowest Price: " + lowestPrice` would also work.